# Three-Phase Thyristor Bridge Converter Simulation on Matlab

Tags: rectifier, matlab, simulink, thyristor

I am looking for a 24 pulse rectifier to power an electrolyser using a universal thyristor bridge from matlab. I am using a phase shifting zig zag transformer for this. The transformers are shifted by 15° from each other. The problem is that I get curves that are not suitable. Do you have any idea what the problem might be? How and in what order should I switch on the universal bridges?

On the first picture you have the complete circuit.

The second picture shows the load that is being fed (a PEM electrolyzer cell)

The third picture shows the current and the rectified voltage
[image: 24 pulse thyristor rectifier]

[image: Electrolyzer's cell]

[image: Output: Current and voltage]

Comment: Ua, Ub, Uc are not in "good" order (not +/- 120°).

Comment: Does this need the "inverted" phases, too? Um - "red" looks the inverse of "yellow" to begin with. (What's the "membrane" picture about?)

Comment: The second picture shows the load that is being fed (a PEM electrolyzer cell)

Comment: Please label, in the schematic, the nodes shown as a, b, and c in the *Scope 3* plot. (I don't see the transformer wired for *different* phase shifts.)

Comment: How many cells will you be operating in series? Total power? Up to 10 kW it may be hard to beat boost PFC, forward converter&synchronous rectifier.